# Does this.props is defined only in the component which will render?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was trying to pass props from parent to child component.
While I was calling this.props inside render its working fine But when I am calling it inside function which will not render (help me do calculation) the console value is "undefined".
Please answer this question with explanation?

Comment: Is this specific to reactjs? Cause if it is, then i don't think you should be facing any issues with this.props in any of the methods

Comment: Please, provide the code sample. Normally, you pass props as `(props) => {your component}`. And they are accessible as normal variables in scope.

Comment: Can you share your code, or at least just the `render` part and your other function where `this.props` is not working

Comment: Parent render:                                                            sortByUserView(){;
 return(
  <div>
   <div>
    <PutawaySortByUser                              
                                      sortedData={this.state.sortedData} 
                                      productToSearch= 
                                                    {this.state.productSearchText}  
                                      selectedIdentity={this.state.selectedIdentity}        
                                />
    </div>
   </div>
  );
 }

Comment: Child Component render...                                                                                            render(){
  console.log( this.props.sortedData) // this value is consoled
  return(
   <div>
    <div>{this.allUserJobView()}</div>
   </div>
  );
 }                                                                                                           function1(){   console.log(this.props.sortedData) // output undefined }          componentDidMount(){ this.function1() }        ..... why the "this.props.sortedData" is giving undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the function member of the class? In other words, has the function been bind to the class?

Value will be undefined if the function doesn't know what class it belong to. Bind it to a class, then you'll get your value.

For instance -

An unbinded function will look like this

```
abc() {
  console.log(this); //this will be undefined here
}
```

A binded function will look like this

```
constructor() {
  this.abc = this.abc.bind(this);
}
abc() {
  console.log(this); //this will have a value
}
```

In case, you want to skip writing `bind` you can follow the new syntax

```
abc = () => {
  console.log(this); //this will have a value
}
```

Finally, you'll be calling your function like `this.abc()`

Comment: even if we define function inside a component we need to bind  it. So that I can access the "this" or "this.props".?                                       But even without binding I have been using it to get value of state variable. How come it worked?

Comment: You must have been using them in the `react` methods like `componentDidMount`,`componentWillMount` etc

Answer (score 1):

Please bind the function to the class either in the constructor or using `.bind`